# Count Down Timer in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have two time.. one fetched directly as string(@"21:00") and other is the current time. I want to display a count down timer showing how much time left from now to reach 21:00.

For eg: the label i use should display "You have 3hrs and 30 minutes left.." if the current time is 17:30.
thanks..

Comment: See my answer, I have provided complete working sample code which does what you asked exactly

Comment: Alex thankyoy for taking such an interesrt in this. Now i have done up with what i exactly needed. thanks..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK have completely revised my answer, and have created a complete solution to the problem, with fully tested sample code available on [github](https://github.com/alexcoplan/Countdown).

Enjoy :)

Comment: I want this time compare with current time and display in a label as a timer running back ward.

Comment: i wll seee one minute tghanks

Comment: OK have made a mistake (with the hours, *minutes*, and seconds) I will actually make this project and post the code here in a couple of minutes

Comment: Have u tested it .??seems warnings and errors cud you fix it!!

Comment: You should get +100 points for effort Alex. The OP seems to not want to do or learn anything for himself, which is a shame.

Comment: @Ian1971 I agree. Alex Coplan +1 for having the energy.

Comment: I have already done up with what Lan has provided. Since i didnt have such a time to think as i have been with many stuffs..Till I found what i exactly need from Lan. but For the energy Alex shown for this,I accept this.Thanks all..This is the reason for what I Trust Stack overflow!!

Comment: Awesome sample code. I really appreciate the time you've taken to make the code and give the answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do it. This will give you the remaining time in seconds. Then you just need to to standard timer stuff as indicated in other answers.

```
//assumption: targetTime is after now
NSString *targetTime = @"21:00";

//split our time into components
NSArray *timeSplit = [targetTime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

NSUInteger hours =  [[timeSplit objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
NSUInteger minutes =  [[timeSplit objectAtIndex:1] intValue];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

//split now into year month day components
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [currentCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];

//set our time components from above
[dateComponents setHour:hours];
[dateComponents setMinute:minutes];

NSDate *targetDate = [currentCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

//ensure target is after now
if ([targetDate timeIntervalSinceDate:now] < 0)
{
    NSDateComponents *day = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [day setDay:1];

    targetDate = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:day toDate:targetDate options:0]; 
}

NSTimeInterval timeRemaining = [targetDate timeIntervalSinceDate:now];
```

Comment: I would make it into a method and call it from within the timer method, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: I Have already done with your code and got what i need exactly.But for the effort Alex has taken to clear my queries reserves something..and he has also given the same stuff what i need, so i accept his answer!!Thanks once again Ian for making me do the thing as exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You create a NSTimer that fires every second:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(tickClock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

When it fires, you enter a method:

```
- (void)tickClock;
```

in there, you compare the date you have against the current date `[NSData currentDate]`;

Like

```
NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:yourDate];
```

where distanceBetweenDates is specified in seconds.

To create a date from your string create a NSDate accordingly

```
NSInteger year = 2011;
NSInteger month = 8;
NSInteger day = 26;
NSInteger hour = 21;
NSInteger minute = 0;
NSInteger second = 0;    


 NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
 NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
 [components setYear:year];
 [components setMonth:month];
 [components setDay:day];
 [components setHour:hour];
 [components setMinute:minute];
 [components setSecond:second];
  NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
 [components release];
```

Comment: i didnt have a date!!! I have only a string i said as 21:00. what i would do then??